# Groovy String that is constrained to uppercase

Tags: grails, groovy

I am creating a domain class that stores country ISO code and country name.

```
class Country {
   String countryISO
   String countryName
   static constraints = {
      countryISO size:2, unique
   }
}
```

But I want to restrict the `countryISO` to contain only uppercase letters as per the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 standard. How it can be achieved?

Tim Yates did point out that there is a similar question on how to change it to upper case. The thing is that I do not really want to change it, I want to restrict it. I.e anyone who enters a code that is not upper case  should get an error.

Answer (score 1):

as simple as

```
class Country {
   String countryISO
   static constraints = {
      countryISO size:2, unique:true, validator:{ it.toUpperCase() == it }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`matches` constraint](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Constraints/matches.html) to check the value against a regular expression:

```
static constraints = {
  countryISO size:2, unique:true, matches:'[A-Z]{2}'
}
```

Comment: @JeffScottBrown it's redundant in validation terms but it affects the DB schema generation, allowing the column to be a varchar(2) instead of a varchar(255)